# Want to avoid adding extra space between css class declaration by using ckeditor

Tags: html, ckeditor

Editor is adding extra spaces between css class declaration for example

```
<div align="center" class="sidebar-nav  ">
```

It should be

```
<div align="center" class="sidebar-nav">
```

I know that it doesnt make any difference. But we are using div tags to create html field which require css classes with no space in it.

Suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Dreamweaver software as it has one feature that helps you remove extra spaces...

Answer (score 0):

How did you create this div element in CKEditor? Make sure to provide exact steps on how did you end up with such markup and there is a chance that someone will fix it.

You can fill a bug directly at http://dev.ckeditor.com/ but note that you need to provide more details than you provided so far as it's hard to guess what has happened based on the current information.